# Only landscape is being applied

Tags: html, ipad, css

My CSS (in an external .css file) is as follows:

```
   @media all and (orientation:portrait) {

            #slider {
                    border: 10px solid black;
            }


    }
    @media all and (orientation:landscape) {

            #slider {
                    border: 1px solid blue;
            }

    }
```

No matter if I am portrait or landscape only the blue border shows.  I am testing in the iPad simulator.

EDIT: Someone on my other thread said the "Same rule is being applied twice in the same context".  I do not understand.  One is portrait, the other is landscape.

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287426/only-landscape-css-is-working-ipad/14287493#14287493) showed another rule. Is this the correct one?

Comment: Yes.  This is it.  One is portrait, the other is landscape.  iPad sim is the one that comes with XCODE.

Comment: Can you post your markup?